# Docker: error loading seccomp filter into kernel

Tags: docker

I have the following error when trying to restart containers.
Has anyone had a similar problem?

Error response from daemon:

> Cannot restart container {container-name}: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: error loading seccomp filter into kernel: loading seccomp filter: errno 524: unknown

Docker version 20.10.12
OS RockyLinux 8.5